# The error in example of Java Specification?

Tags: java, type-conversion, primitive

There are two main kinds of primitive conversion:

- widening conversion;
- narrowing conversion.

I'm reading about widening conversion in [Java SE Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) and here I'm seeing the following picture:

[image]

```
int big = 1234567890;
float approx = big; // good, it's widening conversion (int -> float)
System.out.println(big - (int)approx); // what? (float -> int)
```

In last line of code, I think it's **narrowing** conversion, am I right? If I'm wrong, explain me please! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the *last* line uses a narrowing conversion, which is why a cast is necessary. The example is used to demonstrate that the widening conversion on the middle line loses information, that's all:

> This program prints `-46` thus indicating that information was lost during the conversion from type int to type float because values of type float are not precise to nine significant digits.